# How I can routing my topic to client in a mqtt broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have four mqtt client which two of gonna be connect together and two others connect together. For example Client A publish data to client B on topic /AtoB and client X publish data to client Y on topic /XtoY.
now I am going to route this two topic on a mqtt broker on my PC. 
How I should setup my broker? and Also I found mqtt libraries for mqtt client but I didn't found(is it possible?) library to write a mqtt broker.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

MQTT is a pub/sub protocol and as such designed to totally decouple the publisher from the subscriber.

This means that a publishing client doesn't need to care about what (or how many) clients may be subscribed to a topic (removing any need for "routing").

In the example you gave, Client A publishes to topic `AtoB`*  Client B will subscribe to that topic. Likewise Client X publishes to topic `XtoY` and Client Y subscribes. If an app on your PC wants to receive the same messages then it would also subscribe to both topics `AtoB` and `XtoY` and would receive the same messages.

The second question part of your question about libraries. Normally there would be no need to use a library to create a broker, just use one of the existing brokers. If you REALLY REALLY need to do something none standard then there are libraries like [mosca](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) to implement custom brokers.

*topics do not need to start with a `/` and doing so adds an extra layer of complexity best avoided.